# Answer edit differs largely from original

Tags: discussion, answers

[The original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39666451/1) to a question is quite different from [the edited version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39666451/2). The first version missed quite a bit of what the question was asking. After a comment which stated that the answer missed the mark, the answer was edited quite a bit - enough so that it made me think that the edit might be better served as a new answer. The edit of the answer even says "Tried something different".

Is this something that should be rolled back?

Comment: A wrong (or unhelpful) answer was improved by the OP themselves within a few minutes after creation. I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: No, while it's not always the best behavior, answers are free to start simple and expand/add fixes. The user does this at the peril of downvotes before the answer is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No action needed, and I definitely don't see any reason to rollback edit that made answer correct.

It is expected and welcome on SO to react to comments by updating post whether it is question or answer.

There is no reason to keep invalid answers around (short of "you may try {some invalid steps}, but it will not work because {explanation}"). Adding correct answer as new one (instead of editing existing one) does not add any value to SO and opens poster to downvotes. In rare cases providing alternative answer with second *valid* solution may be useful, but that causes META questions/improper votes (even if it is completely ok).